Tom Select - Preventing Selection of Child Options When Parent is Selected
I'm using Tom Select with a multi-select dropdown for a folder structure where options are grouped by parent folders. For example, if I select a top-level folder like app, I want any child options like app/Helpers or app/Http to automatically be disabled, preventing them from being selected.
Here's the current setup:

Using Tom Select with the checkbox_options plugin.
The select field includes optgroup elements, and options have data-groups attributes to indicate their parent grouping.

HTML Structure:
<select id="myFolders" name="folders[]" multiple autocomplete="off">
    <optgroup label="app">
        <option value="app" selected>app</option>
        <option value="app/Helpers">app/Helpers</option>
        <option value="app/Http">app/Http</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

Javascript I tried.
const tomSelect = new TomSelect('#myFolders', {
    plugins: {
        'checkbox_options': {
            'checkedClassNames':   ['ts-checked'],
            'uncheckedClassNames': ['ts-unchecked'],
            'className': 'form-check-input'
        },
        'remove_button': {
            title:'Remove this item',
        }
    },
    onChange: function () {
        updateDisabledOptions(this);
    }
});

function updateDisabledOptions(tomSelectInstance) {
    const selectedValues = tomSelectInstance.getValue();
    const selectedGroups = new Set(selectedValues);

    Object.values(tomSelectInstance.options).forEach(option => {
        const optionElement = document.querySelector(`.ts-dropdown [data-value="${option.value}"]`);
        
        if (optionElement) {
            const checkbox = optionElement.querySelector('.form-check-input');

            if (checkbox) {
                const isChildOfSelectedGroup = Array.from(selectedGroups).some(
                    group => option.value.startsWith(group + '/')
                );

                if (isChildOfSelectedGroup) {
                    optionElement.classList.add('disabled');
                    checkbox.setAttribute('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    optionElement.classList.remove('disabled');
                    checkbox.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

Problem: The function is adding the disabled attribute to child checkboxes, but it doesn’t prevent them from being selected. Even with aria-disabled and disabled attributes set, the checkboxes are still selectable.
Expected Outcome: If a parent folder like app is selected, any child folders (e.g., app/Helpers) should be automatically disabled and not selectable.
Questions:

Is there a way to ensure the child checkboxes become non-selectable in Tom Select when their parent is selected?
Am I missing any specific handling in Tom Select to achieve this?

Any suggestions or code modifications are welcome! Thank you in advance.
The jsFiddle link Here
(No Jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/93bd7m1v/ I tried, it worked but now the children have problems =))

@LãNgọcHải thanks, your Idea give me clear structure to improve the updateDisbaledOptions at the same time, if child selected and later parent select the child will be auto removed.. and I will share the final code.

thanks, @La Ngoc, I changed the function updateDisbaledOptions when the child selected and later user select the parent the selected child will be auto removed. here is the final function.. maybe helpful for others.
 const updateDisabledOptions = (tomSelectInstance) => {
            const selectedValues = tomSelectInstance.getValue();
            const parents = [...Object.values(tomSelectInstance.optgroups)].map(o => o.label);

            parents.forEach(parent => {
                const options = [...Object.values(tomSelectInstance.options)];
                const children = options.filter(option => option.value.startsWith(`${parent}/`));

                children.forEach(child => {
                    if (selectedValues.includes(parent)) {
                        tomSelectInstance.removeItem(child.value);
                        tomSelectInstance.updateOption(child.value, {
                            value: child.value,
                            text: child.text,
                            disabled: true,
                        });
                    } else {
                        tomSelectInstance.updateOption(child.value, {
                            value: child.value,
                            text: child.text,
                            disabled: false,
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
};


like I said in the comment the children have problem: toggling selection via clicking on the option doesnt work correctly. I tried your code on jsFiddle and it still has that problem. Might have something to do with the checkbox plugin
